# How do I correctly use generics in this case?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, interface

Below is my Transformer Interface

```
public interface Transformer<BusinessObject, O extends State>
{
    public O transformToState(BusinessObject input);
}
```

This is one of my Transformer Impl

```
public class GoldTransformer implements Transformer<BusinessObject, Gold>
{
    @Override
    public Gold transformToState(BusinessObject input) {
        GoldBO goldbo= (GoldBO) input; // redundant casting line
        //do some transformation with BO to make it a state with some business logic
    }
}
```

Here is my another Transformer Impl

```
public class SilverTransformer implements Transformer<BusinessObject, Sliver> 
{
    @Override
    public Gold transformToState(BusinessObject input) {
        SilverBO goldbo= (SilverBO) input; // redundant casting line
        // again do some transformation with BO to make it a state with some business logic
    }
}
```

Both `SilverBO` and `GoldBO` Implements `BusinessObject` which is a marker interface. And `Silver` and `Gold` extend `State`. I really find the casting annoying and redundant is there a better way to use generics here? or a better pattern to use? I don't want to make any changes to `state` i.e. gold and silver.

Comment: What is the relation between `Gold` and `GoldBO`?

Comment: GoldBO has some extra attributes and isn't directly a copy of Gold. Based on Business logic I decide what values should go to Gold state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could generalize the interface on the input `BusinessObject` too:

```
public interface Transformer<I extends BusinessObject, O extends State> {
    public O transformToState(I input);
}

public class GoldTransformer implements Transformer<GoldBO, Gold> {    
    @Override
    public Gold transformToState(GoldBO input) {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like BusinessObject is a class, but you're also using the same identifier as a generic type parameter! In this code, BusinessObject does not refer to your class, it's a distinct identifier. If it's in a different package, you can verify this by verifying that it does not need to be imported.

```
interface Transformer<BusinessObject, O extends State>
{
    public O transformToState(BusinessObject input);
}
```

This is **semantically identical** to:

```
interface Transformer<FlyingSpaghettiMonster, O extends State>
{
    public O transformToState(FlyingSpaghettiMonster input);
}
```

Any decent IDE will colour generic type parameters differently to help you differentiate them. See below, the real type parameters are white, while the generic type parameters are dark green:

[image: generic type parameter highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA]

While you should change the generic type parameter to avoid confusion, all you technically need to do to remove the casting is change your transformer implementations like so:

```
public class GoldTransformer implements Transformer<GoldBO, Gold>
{                                                 // ^ changed
    @Override
    public Gold transformToState(GoldBO input) {
                                // ^ changed
    }
}
```

However, it's possible (or *likely*) that you'll also want to enforce that the first type parameter is a subclass of BusinessObject, otherwise it would be possible to create a `Transformer<String, Gold>`. To do this, change your interface to:

```
public interface Transformer<I extends BusinessObject, O extends State>
{
    public O transformToState(I input);
}
```

Where `I` is now the generic type parameter and BusinessObject is a real type which does refer to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Make the input generic as well:

```
public interface Transformer<I extends BusinessObject, O extends State> {
    public O transformToState(I input);
}
```

Silver example:

```
public class SilverTransformer implements Transformer<SilverBO, Silver> {    

    @Override
    public Silver transformToState(SilverBO input) {
         return new Silver(input); // an example, perform the transformation...
    }   
}
```

---

**Java 8 gives a shorter way**

Alternatively, if you use Java 8 or higher, the `Transformer<BusinessObject, O extends State>` does exactly the same as `java.util.Function<BusinessObject, O extends State>`. Therefore the interface would be not needed. The usage is pretty neat:

```
Function<SilverBO, Silver> silverTransformer = (input -> new Silver(input));
Silver silver = silverTransformer.apply(silverBo);
```

Perform the transformation directly inside the lambda expression. If the transformation takes more lines, use the brackets `{}` and `return`.

```
Function<SilverBO, Silver> silverTransformer = (input -> {
    Silver output = // transformation ... 
    // ... more transformation ...
    return output;
});
```

Comment: quick question `BusinessObject` is a marker interface and my `SilverBO` implements BusinessObject not extends it. would <I extends BusinessObject> still work?

Comment: @Kid101: See the revision, I had corrected this mistake 4 minutes before you have added the comment :)

Comment: low bandwidth  :)